# Doctrine fixture - Set order as 'last'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony project I already use ordered Doctrine fixtures implementing the needed interface `Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface`.

Therefore in every fixture I declare the relative function

```
public function getOrder()
{
    // return 1;
    // return 2;
    // return 3;
    // ...
}
```

returning different values according to the order I want. Now I would like to execute one fixture as last and thus I wonder if there's already a way to do it, something like

```
public function getOrder()
{
    return 'last';
}
```

Is there already an implemented logic ready to use or do I have to write it by myself?

Comment: `return 99` or stuff like that will do the job, no need to do more for fixtures

Comment: Or `return 5000000;`. Same as `z-index` really :D